# SOAPUI 5.3 facing issue NoClassDefFoundError com/eviware/soapui/analytics/Analytics

Tags: analytics, soapui, noclassdeffounderror

Project gets loaded after disabling plugins as mentioned in one of post but now i am facing issue with `com.eviware.soapui.analytics.Analytics` not found at the time of addTestStep.

I verified in latest soapui-5.3.0 jar and that class is not available. I don't know if that class is available in some other SOAPUI version?

I am using community version (Open Source). Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to the [article](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Cannot-compile-the-source-code-of-branch-quot-release-5-3-0-quot/m-p/132626/highlight/true#M22598)

If you are using maven, then use below dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.smartbear.utils.analytics</groupId>
<artifactId>analytics-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.smartbear.utils.analytics</groupId>
<artifactId>out-app-analytics-provider</artifactId>
<version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, [download](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/utils/analytics/) the jar files from below location for `Soapui 5.3.0` and copy them under `SOAPUI_HOME/lib` and restart SoapUI tool.

[analytics-core-5.3.0.jar](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/utils/analytics/analytics-core/5.3.0/analytics-core-5.3.0.jar)
[out-app-analytics-provider-5.3.0.jar](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/utils/analytics/out-app-analytics-provider/5.3.0/out-app-analytics-provider-5.3.0.jar)